# Select2JS tags options is not working with input text

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm currently using `Select2` and tried the `tags: true` option, but when I tried to enter or create value, it does not added to the input. Please see my fiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/ek54r3oq/

Comment: potentially silly question: why are you using `<input type="text" class="select">` for this? your JSFiddle works perfectly fine if I replace the input with `<select class="select"></select>`...